# Bubble sort issue in asm using vc++

Tags: loops, visual-c++, assembly, masm, irvine32

This program just runs fine, but output is not correct

```
 INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

 .data
 array BYTE 5,4,3,2,1
 .code
 main PROC
 mov ecx,lengthof array

 l1:
 mov esi,0
 mov eax,0
 l2:
 mov al,array[esi]
 cmp al,array[esi+1]
 jbe noswap

 mov dl,array[esi+1]
 mov array[esi+1],al
 mov array[esi],dl

 noswap:
 add esi,1
 cmp esi,ecx
 jne l2

 loop l1

 mov esi,0
 mov esi,offset array
 mov ecx,lengthof array
 mov ebx,type array 
 call dumpmem

exit
main ENDP
END main
```

It gives the following output:
00 01 02 03 04

It is not showing 5 at the end. I think there is a problem in looping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `ecx` will start out at `lengthof array` (which is 5), and will go down to 1 (the `loop` instruction won't jump back to `l1` when `ecx` becomes 0). This leads to problems in the inner loop: the first is that `esi` will never become 0, so you'll never be comparing the elements at positions 0 and 1; the other is that you'll be comparing the elements at positions 4 and 5 during the first iteration of `l1`. The array only has 5 elements, so position 5 is past the end of the array, since the positions are zero-based.

You should instead initialize `ecx` to `(lengthof array)-1`. If MASM doesn't like that syntax, use `lengthof array` and put a `dec ecx` on the next line.
And the `loop l1` line should be changed to `dec ecx` followed by `jns l1`. That way `ecx` will go from `4..0`, instead of from `5..1`.

Comment: but i am moving 0 in esi before entering in inner loop,and secondly loop is same if it is from 5..1 or 4..0 because i am not using ecx as index of array.I moved 0 in esi before this instruction mov al,array[esi]. 
And I am comparing using esi not ecx and i am incrementing it at the end
cmp al,array[esi+1]
It will compare fisrt and second element

Comment: now it is working fine :) 
esi is ok ,only problem was with inner loop